# How to bind a vuex array element to an input?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue component with a list of `paramNames` as a prop. There's also a vuex store containing an object `values` imported into the component, indexed by the same names.

I'd like to use `v-for` to create input elements for each name, and bind each input to `values[name]` but that doesn't work because it doesn't call the vuex setter.

Short version:

```html
<input v-for="name in paramNames" v-model="values[name]">
```

but that doesn't work because when the user updates the input, it doesn't call the `values` vuex setter to create a mutation, it just updates `values[name]` directly (which you're not supposed to do with vuex). Is there a best-practices Vue/Vuex way to do this?

Comment: Use computed getter setter - in setter commit updates

Comment: The setter for `values` doesn't get triggered because I'm only updating a property of the object, not the `values` object as a whole.

Comment: You may need to forgo using `v-model` for this and instead bind `:value` and add an `@input` handler. How does `paramNames` relate to `values`?

Comment: `paramNames` (array of string) is independent, but contains names of some properties of `values`. I was afraid someone would say I can't use `v-model` for this. Seems like a "normal" sort of thing to do but perhaps not.

Comment: Alternatively is there any way to destructure the elements of `values` (which is a vuex object) as individual named reactive objects in the component?

Comment: Here's a codepen to play with: https://codepen.io/oberbrunner/pen/OJLOBXV